# Power series expansion using Taylors Theorem.

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

So the function $f(x)=3x^2-6x+5$ needs to be written as a power series expansion around $x=a$ and the goal is to show $x=a$ is $f(x)$ for every $a$. So I started off by finding up to the third derivative and then plugged in $a$ for $x$. From there, I set up the series and got $3a^2-6a+5(x-a/1!)+6a-12((x-a)^2/2!)+12a((x-a)^3/3!)$. First I dont know how to represent that in summation notation and second how do I show that $x=a$ is $f(x)$ for every $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=y(a)+y'(a)(x-a)+\frac{y''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2$$

$$y'=6x-6$$

$$y''=6$$
at x=a 
$$y'(a)=6a-6$$
$$y''(a)=6$$
subsitute in the general series to get
$$y=3a^2-6a+5+(6a-6)(x-a)+3(x-a)^2$$
$$y=3a^2-6a+5+6ax-6a^2-6x+6a+3x^2-6ax+3a^2=3x^2-6x+5$$
that means the function not change for any value of $a$

Answer (score 0):

You made some computational mistakes.

$$f(x) = f(a) + f^{\prime}(a)(x-a) + f^{\prime\prime}(a) (x-a)^{2}/2! + \dots$$

In your case,

$$f(x) = 3a^{2} -6a + 5 + (6a-6)(x-a) + 3(x-a)^{2}$$

with all higher derivatives equal to zero. Simplify the RHS from here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an a way to do this in which it will be clear that the power series is equal to $f(x)$.

Let $x=y+a$, then
$$\begin{align}
f(x) & =3(y+a)^2-6(y+a)+5=3y^2+6ay+3a^2-6y-6a+5\\
& =3y^2+(6a-6)y+(3a^2-6a+5)
\end{align}$$
and since $y=x-a$,

$$f(x)=3(x-a)^2+(6a-6)(x-a)+(3a^2-6a+5).$$